# Is there an introductory book on Genetic Sequencing Theory for mathematicians?

Tags: book-recommendation, biology

I am interested in Genetic Sequencing Theory (see the wikipedia link over [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_sequencing_theory)), and I was wondering whether there is some introduction to this field for someone with a mathematics background and little knowledge on genetics.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with [Statistical Methods in Bioinformatics: An Introduction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441923020)

Another good introduction is [Computational Genome Analysis: An Introduction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387987851)